# Modifying array prototype causes foreach to behave differently

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I noticed that whenever i modify an array prototype it changes the behavior of foreachs. I have created the example below to show you guys what im doing:

```
Array.prototype.x = 10;
for(var i in [1,2,3]){
    alert(i);
}
```

This example shows four alerts: "1", "2", "3" and "x";

Why this code give me 4 alerts?

How can i modify array prototype without interfere with the foreach ?

Comment: Of course! You add one more enumerable property to all array instances. Why are you surprised?

Comment: It is generally considered a bad idea to use a for/in loop for arrays.  Stick to using for/in with objects, and a regular for loop for arrays.  However, you can extend `Array.prototype` without making the extensions enumerable; see bfontaine's correct answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your property as “non-enumerable”:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'x', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: 10
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quztJ/) that shows the code in action.